# auto select radio button not triggering routes

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am writing code in angular. I tried auto select in radio button but it is not triggering click event. Need to click radio button again to generate event.
Here is what i did

```
     <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">

                    <mat-radio-button value="2" routerLink='/products/tshirt/shirt' [checked]='true'><span>Shirt</span></mat-radio-button><br>
                    <mat-radio-button value="3"><span>Cap</span></mat-radio-button>
                  </mat-radio-group>
```

i am getting checked radio button but routes doesnot works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set the routerLink attribute for the `mat-radio-button`. But you could navigate on the change event of the radio button:

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
   <mat-radio-button value="2" (change)="changeRoute($event)"><span>Shirt</span></mat-radio-button>
   <mat-radio-button value="3" (change)="changeRoute($event)"><span>Cap</span></mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

And in ts file you can change the route according to the selected value:

```
 private changeRoute(event:MatRadioChange){
    if(event.value === "2"){
      this.router.navigate(['/products/tshirts/shirt']);
    }
  }
```

And in your ts file don't forget to inject the router:

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
```

Comment: i am trying for auto select radio button event

Comment: ah...i see, sorry i misunderstood you. After looking in the source code of mat-radio-button the change event only triggers if check state changes due to user input.
Would it be sufficient for you to set the initial route on ngOnInit() with router.navigate ?

Comment: thanks it work after setting navigate to ngOnInit()